# How can I make some file visible for processes and when some process access it then feed content of some internet stream?

Tags: linux, file, file-io, filesystems

One process (Twonky – DLNA server) check directory for files to feed them on demand through DLNA to TV. When I put to this directory .mpeg file Twonky updates it's database.

I want to put into directory something like file but when it will be accessed by Twonky to feed it's content to TV feed content stream from internet.

It will be brilliant if that will be shell-programmable solution but c programming is welcome too.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to make some http content visible as a local file, you might want to check something like fuse's [httpfs](http://httpfs.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: I think it is great and it is that what I need. Thanks a lot!
The last thing that I need is to find httpfs compiled for arm cpu or another arm-compatible solution.

Answer (score 0):

You might also look at using a [FIFO](http://www.google.com.au/search?q=bash+fifo).

Comment: Thanks! Can you explain how exactly I might use it? How to detect named pipe read access? Can I do this via some shell scripting?

Comment: @EddieGems: I updated the link to a more appropriate one for your use case.